# Django Oracle Database - Varchar2 Vs NVarchar2

Tags: django, django-models, oracle10g, django-orm, django-oracle

I have the following character field in my model (against Oracle Database).

```
trans_status = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

Why does Django create this field as NVARCHAR2 instead of VARCHAR2? I mean,

Why

```
trans_status           NVARCHAR2(10)  NULL,
```

instead of

```
trans_status           VARCHAR2(10)  NULL,
```

What is the difference? How does Django decide on one and not the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NVARCHAR2** will store the data with 16-bit characters, and **VARCHAR2** will store the data with 8-bit characters.
The difference that **NVARCHAR2** will store unicode characters like Arabic characters, but it'll consume double size more than **VARCHAR2**.